# Problema a la hora de ejecutar un AutoScroll a un div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, div

Este es el código jQuery para autoScroll a un div que estoy utilizando pero no me funciona. He intentado de todas formas y nada de hacer que funcione, Si me pueden ayudar estare muy agradecido.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
                function scroll_to(div){
                 $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $(".col-md-10").offset().top
                 },1000);
                }
                </script>
               <p>La Organización Mundial de la Salud ha lanzado un fondo para la lucha contra el COVID-19, este fondo se utilizará para combatir la pandemia, asimismo informó que ya recibió sus primeras donaciones y detalló los montos y los países que lo hicieron, según los cuales, Japón y Alemania, seguidos por China, son los países que más han donado.</p>

    <p>A pesar de ello, menos de un tercio de 675 millones de dólares han sido recaudados. A fecha de hoy, la OMS ha recibido 195 millones de dólares y compromisos de 69 millones.</p>

    <p>Japón es por ahora el mayor contribuyente, con donaciones por valor de 47.5 millones de dólares, seguido por Alemania con 27 millones de dólares.</p>

    <p>Les siguen China (20 millones de dólares), Reino Unido (17.4 millones), Estados Unidos (14.7 millones de dólares), el Fondo de Respuesta a Emergencias de Naciones Unidas (10 millones de dólares) y a continuación un donante privado, la Fundación Bill and Melinda Gates, con ayuda por valor de 9.5 millones de dólares.</p>
                <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-md-12 whast" id="whast">
            <div class="col-md-1" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
             
            <div class="col-md-10" align="center">
            <h3>hola</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco en qué momento realizas el llamado a la funcion `scroll_to`, pero agregué un boton y al momento de darle click invoco la función y funciona bien tu código, ademas tambien en la funcion quite el parametro `div` porque no le encuentro el sentido que le envies un div cuando en tu funcion tienes la clase del div.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
                function scroll_to(){
                 $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $(".col-md-10").offset().top
                 },1000);
                }
window.onload = scroll_to
                </script>

               <p>La Organización Mundial de la Salud ha lanzado un fondo para la lucha contra el COVID-19, este fondo se utilizará para combatir la pandemia, asimismo informó que ya recibió sus primeras donaciones y detalló los montos y los países que lo hicieron, según los cuales, Japón y Alemania, seguidos por China, son los países que más han donado.</p>

    <p>A pesar de ello, menos de un tercio de 675 millones de dólares han sido recaudados. A fecha de hoy, la OMS ha recibido 195 millones de dólares y compromisos de 69 millones.</p>

    <p>Japón es por ahora el mayor contribuyente, con donaciones por valor de 47.5 millones de dólares, seguido por Alemania con 27 millones de dólares.</p>

    <p>Les siguen China (20 millones de dólares), Reino Unido (17.4 millones), Estados Unidos (14.7 millones de dólares), el Fondo de Respuesta a Emergencias de Naciones Unidas (10 millones de dólares) y a continuación un donante privado, la Fundación Bill and Melinda Gates, con ayuda por valor de 9.5 millones de dólares.</p>
                <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-md-12 whast" id="whast">
            <div class="col-md-1" align="center">
            <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
             
            <div class="col-md-10" align="center">
            <h3>hola</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
            </a>
```

Comment: lo que pasa es que quiero que haga el scroll automáticamente a la hora de cargar la pagina, sin acudir a un click en el boton

Comment: Ya actualice mi respuesta, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el evento window.onload, para que al momento que tu pagina se carga, haga el scroll

Comment: Mil gracias brot